# Android Animation: How to trigger it automatically and make continuous in and out zooming

Tags: android, android-animation

I am learning about animation in Android and have following code (based on Android-Developer tutorial) which works when I click on the ImageButton.  On click, it will zoom-in and then on next click, it will zoom-out.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.container_layout);

    final View thumb1View = findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_1);
    thumb1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            zoomImageFromThumb(thumb1View, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        }
    });

    mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_longAnimTime);
}
```

And this is the layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_1" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- This initially-hidden ImageView will hold the expanded/zoomed version of
         the images above. Without transformations applied, it takes up the entire
         screen. To achieve the "zoom" animation, this view's bounds are animated
         from the bounds of the thumbnail button above, to its final laid-out
         bounds.
         -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="100dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_zoom_touch_close" />
</FrameLayout>
```

However, I am trying to make it to keep zooming in/out once activity is loaded without need to click to activate it, then on click stop the zooming.

Much appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by using animation xml in res/anim directory.  Add new xml called my_alpha_animation.xml in your res/anim directory, if anim does not existe, create it:

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="0.1"
    android:fromYScale="0.1"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse">
</scale>
```

and loading it on Activities onResume():

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    doAlpha(btnAlpha);
}
```

And here is the method that does it:

```
private void doAlpha(View v){
    Animation alphaAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.my_alpha_animation);
    image.startAnimation(alphaAnimation); //image is my ImageView
}
```

Above, "image" is my ImageView for which I set image called "scanweb" from my mipmap directory and clear any animation that might be in progress in my Activity onCreate():

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.scanweb);
image.clearAnimation();
```

The end result is that once Activity is created, my image "scanweb" starts pulsating (zooming in/out) infinitely.